# Extension installation prefill table

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

Hi I want to add some data during extension installation ...

I've added an SQL statement after table creation but that will be ignored during installation.

```
#
# Insert für start einstellungen
#
INSERT INTO tx_rere_domain_model_intervall (type,aktuell) VALUES ('studienhalbjahr','WS14/15');
```

This code is directly after the Create Statement of `tx_rere_domain_model_intervall`

UPDATE:
    # TYPO3 Extension Manager dump 1.1
    #
    #--------------------------------------------------------

```
#
# Table structure for table 'tx_rere_domain_model_interval'
#
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tx_rere_domain_model_intervall;
CREATE TABLE tx_rere_domain_model_intervall (
uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

type varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
aktuell varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,

tstamp int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
crdate int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
cruser_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
deleted tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
hidden tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
starttime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
endtime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

t3ver_oid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_wsid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_label varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
t3ver_state tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_stage int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_count int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_tstamp int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
t3ver_move_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

sys_language_uid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
l10n_parent int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
l10n_diffsource mediumblob,

PRIMARY KEY (uid),
KEY parent (pid),
KEY t3ver_oid (t3ver_oid,t3ver_wsid),
KEY language (l10n_parent,sys_language_uid)
);

INSERT INTO tx_rere_domain_model_intervall (type,aktuell) VALUES ('studienhalbjahr','WS14/15');
```

Comment: A general comment to the extension you're developing: Since you're obviously planning to release it in TER (or already did), I would suggest that you use English domain and property names instead of German ones. This makes it easier for non-German speaking people to understand your code and will make it more likely that someone will be using the extension and contributing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the ext_tables_static+adt.sql dosn't work ... I've done a workarround with prefilling the table if the table is empty!

Answer (score 5):

To include static data with your extension, you must place the SQL INSERT statements in a file named [ext_tables_static+adt.sql](http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Developers_Guide#ext_tables_static.2Badt.sql_.28optional.29), which should be located in the root directory of your extension.

The content of this file will be imported to the TYPO3 Database when importing the extension with the extension manager.

For a working example please refer to the [static_info_tables](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/static_info_tables) extension.

Comment: thanks. I've added a xt_tables_static+adt.sql to my root directory. and placed my insert statement. but if I run the installation the stamenet weren't placed? Do I have to do some configurations as well?

Comment: Refering to the documentation http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/singlehtml/#extension-architecture you need to dump your static data with the option --add-drop-table and including all fields (also UIDs and PIDs). Inserting the static data only seems to work for me, if I initially import the extension. Afterwards, no data-upgrade seems to be possible. The static_info_tables extension has an upgrade-script for this purpose, so using ext_tables_static+adt.sql may only be useable, if you initially want to import static data.

Comment: yes i only want initaly import data. during the installation process.

Comment: Does the mysqldump command create a "INSERT INTO" statement with just 2 fields? I think that the INSERT statement should contain all fields available from the SQL dump.

Comment: I've tried both, my one with only the 2 inserts. and the one of mysqldump: `INSERT INTO `tx_rere_domain_model_intervall` (`uid`, `pid`, `type`, `aktuell`, `tstamp`, `crdate`, `cruser_id`, `deleted`, `hidden`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `t3ver_oid`, `t3ver_id`, `t3ver_wsid`, `t3ver_label`, `t3ver_state`, `t3ver_stage`, `t3ver_count`, `t3ver_tstamp`, `t3ver_move_id`, `sys_language_uid`, `l10n_parent`, `l10n_diffsource`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'studienhalbjahr', 'SS14', 1419988512, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL);`

nothing is set in database

Comment: That is really strange. Refering to the documentation, this should be the standard way to import static data in an extension and for static_info_tables it works fine. You could do some debugging in the TYPO3 InstallUtility of the extensionmanager extension. The function processDatabaseUpdates() calls importStaticSqlFile() on Extension installation. In this function, the static content from ext_tables_static+adt.sql is imported.

Comment: Oh your from Germany ;) I'm too 

and the file really namend `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` ? How can I do the debugging?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67981/discussion-between-felix-and-derhansen).

Answer (score 0):

When working with `ext_tables_static+adt.sql`, remember to delete the row for your plugin in the table `sys_registry` if the import doesn't work.

Typo3 sets a flag after the import has been done once and future imports will be ignored.